# Display Widget ImageView based on month

Tags: android, android-widget, android-imageview, android-appwidget

I have 12 images saved in drawable with file name named according to month, i.e. jan, feb, mar, apr, etc. How can I display the image in the ImageView of Android widget based on current month? For example, currently is April, so image with file name apr should be display.
I am following tutorial from https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/android-complete-widget-tutorial-including-source-code/

```
public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static int clickCount = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("pl.looksok.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE")){
        updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
    }
}

private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());

    //REMEMBER TO ALWAYS REFRESH YOUR BUTTON CLICK LISTENERS!!!
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(), remoteViews);
}

private int getImageToSet() {
    clickCount++;
    return clickCount % 2 == 0 ? R.drawable.me : R.drawable.wordpress_icon;
}
```

}
What modification I should made? I do not need the button. I only want the image to be displayed based on month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by using `Calendar`.

Comment: Better do it using switch-case or an index in an const array